# Bootstrap button menu on wordpress

Tags: menus, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple 4 item menu on wordpress. I want to use the bootstrap button style for this menu.

This is the hand-made code of what I want to get.

```
<div class="menu-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-menu" class="btn-group">
<li id="menu-item-16" class="btn btn-default"><a href="http://localhost/test/?page_id=5">Link 1</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-15" class="btn btn-default"><a href="http://localhost/test/?page_id=7">Link 2</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="btn btn-default"><a href="http://localhost/test/?page_id=9">Link 3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="btn btn-default"><a href="http://localhost/test/?page_id=11">Link 4</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I have no clue on how to tell wp_nav_menu() to build the menu in this way. 
I am working over twentythirteen as starting theme so I have to change the default menu to this style I want.

I tried to use [this guide](http://josephfitzsimmons.com/home/making-wp_nav_menu-work-with-bootstrap-3s-navbar/) but I wan't able to get the result I want. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should setup your menu with the correct classes and IDs applied to your container and ul. The codex entry for [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) lists all the possible arguments.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'primary', 
    'container_class' => 'menu-menu-container', 
    'menu_id' => 'menu-menu', 
    'menu_class' => 'btn-group' 
) );
```

You can then add the required classes to the menu items by using the [nav_menu_css_class filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class).

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    $classes[] = 'btn btn-default';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This solution does exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to add classes the list items themselves, but it would be easy to wrap a `<span>` with the desired class names around the `<a>`.

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'your-theme-location',
    'before' => '<span class="btn btn-default">',
    'after' => '</span>'
));
```